# Aspose Java - Add Table below a list value

Tags: java, aspose.words

The following is the format I want to generate:

[image]

From my limited experience of the API I know how to make a list

```
ListFormat listFormat = builder.getListFormat();
listFormat.setList(document.getLists().add(ListTemplate.NUMBER_DEFAULT));
builder.writeln("Component Specification")
listFormat.setListLevelNumber(1);
builder.writeln("Raw Material Specification")
```

Now how do I transition from the list to the table below?
writing a new line adds numbers, even in the cells of the table.

If I set the listformat to null then the indentation is lost. I want to maintain the indentation of the list but also add the table below that list value

Anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

@Furqan,

You need to set Table LeftIndent property for your requirements. Please check following sample code snippet.

I am Tilal Ahmad, developer evangelist at Aspose.

```
Document doc= new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder= new DocumentBuilder(doc);

ListFormat listFormat = builder.getListFormat();
listFormat.setList(doc.getLists().add(ListTemplate.NUMBER_DEFAULT));
builder.writeln("Component Specification");
builder.getListFormat().listIndent();
builder.getListFormat().getListLevel().setNumberStyle(NumberStyle.ARABIC);
builder.getListFormat().getListLevel().setNumberFormat("\u0000.\u0001");
builder.writeln("Raw Material Specification");
builder.getListFormat().removeNumbers();

Table table = new Table(doc);

// Add the table to the document.
doc.getFirstSection().getBody().appendChild(table);

Row row1 = new Row(doc);
row1.getRowFormat().setAllowBreakAcrossPages(true);
table.appendChild(row1);


// Create a cell and add it to the row
Cell cell1 = new Cell(doc);
cell1.getCellFormat().getShading()
        .setBackgroundPatternColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
cell1.getCellFormat().setWidth(50);

// Add a paragraph to the cell as well as a new run with some text.
cell1.appendChild(new Paragraph(doc));
cell1.getFirstParagraph().appendChild(new Run(doc, "Col1"));

// Add the cell to the row.
row1.appendChild(cell1);

// We would then repeat the process for the other cells and rows in the
// table.
// We can also speed things up by cloning existing cells and rows.
row1.appendChild(cell1.deepClone(false));
row1.getLastCell().appendChild(new Paragraph(doc));
row1.getLastCell().getFirstParagraph()
        .appendChild(new Run(doc, "Col2"));

row1.appendChild(cell1.deepClone(false));
row1.getLastCell().appendChild(new Paragraph(doc));
row1.getLastCell().getFirstParagraph()
        .appendChild(new Run(doc, "Col3"));


Row row = new Row(doc);
row.getRowFormat().setAllowBreakAcrossPages(true);
table.appendChild(row);

// Create a cell and add it to the row
Cell cell = new Cell(doc);
cell.getCellFormat().setWidth(50);

// Add a paragraph to the cell as well as a new run with some text.
cell.appendChild(new Paragraph(doc));
cell.getFirstParagraph()
        .appendChild(new Run(doc, "Row 1, Cell 1 Text"));

// Add the cell to the row.
row.appendChild(cell);

row.appendChild(cell.deepClone(false));
row.getLastCell().appendChild(new Paragraph(doc));
row.getLastCell().getFirstParagraph()
        .appendChild(new Run(doc, "Row 1, Cell 2 Text"));

row.appendChild(cell.deepClone(false));
row.getLastCell().appendChild(new Paragraph(doc));
row.getLastCell().getFirstParagraph()
        .appendChild(new Run(doc, "Row 1, Cell 3 Text"));
// Add left indent to the table.
table.setLeftIndent(60);


doc.save("E:/Data/Test1.docx");
```